# How to add text in a section of a container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The result I want to have

[image: expected]

My current result

[image: current result]

I was trying to add a title section for my categories but the result was not what I expected.
I'm looking to add a title section below each illustration in my categories.

```
child: Container(
   height: 400.0,
   width: 500.0,
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   color: ColorPallete.secondColor[50],
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
   ),
   child: SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/images/svg/megacategory/art__grocery.svg',
   ),
)
```

Comment: if you want to add a title, you should wrapper the container in a Column widget... so Column(children:[Container(), Text(title])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Column` widget to align its contents vertically, in your example you can use it as follow (I have used some online images and colors you can edit it as per your requirement)-

```
    Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(height: 50.0),
        Container(
          height: 100.0,
          width: 100.0,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.orange[50],
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://img.icons8.com/cotton/online-shop-2--v2.png',
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        Text("Title Here")
      ],
    ),
```

It will arrange the contents as follows -

[image]

You can read more about `Column` widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

Comment: I'm making use of svg saved in a directory of my project, so Image.network doesn't work for me, although I also tried Image.asset and it didn't work either :(

Comment: You can replace Image.Network with `SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/images/svg/megacategory/art__grocery.svg',
   ),` as required by your application. In my answer Network.Image is just an example I used for using icons from Internet as I do not want to use any Svg Icons for example.

Comment: Well I did exactly that and I get the following error: A RenderFlex overflowed by 29 pixels on the bottom.

Comment: You should give an appropriate `height` and `width` to the SvgPicture. Something like this  `SvgPicture.asset(      'assets/images/svg/megacategory/art__grocery.svg', height: 50.0, width: 70.0    ),`

Answer (score 0):

```
child: Container(
   height: 400.0,
   width: 500.0,
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   color: ColorPallete.secondColor[50],
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
   ),
   child: Column(
     children: [
        SvgPicture.asset(
         'assets/images/svg/megacategory/art__grocery.svg',
        ),
        Text('Abarrotes')
)
```

Comment: You need to try with Column

Comment: Error: A RenderFlex overflowed by 329 pixels on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it with Column widget so you can add a Text widget under your container.

```
child: Column(
 children: [ 
  Container(
   height: 400.0,
   width: 500.0,
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
   color: ColorPallete.secondColor[50],
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
   ),
   child: SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/images/svg/megacategory/art__grocery.svg',
   ),
  ),
 Text("Your text",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black) ),
 ],
 ),
```

Comment: Error: A RenderFlex overflowed by 329 pixels on the bottom.

Comment: It seems that it has something to do with the height of the parent widget. What widget are you wrapping this child widget with?

Answer (score 0):

You try put image in decoration instead of child and add text in child container as below.

```
Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(*imageUrl*)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6.0)),
          ),
          child: Text(*title*))
```

Answer (score 0):

As I saw from the answers above you are facing an overflow problem when you are implementing these lines of code:

```
child: Container(
 height: 400.0,
 width: 500.0,
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: ColorPallete.secondColor[50],
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
),
child: Column(
  children: [
    SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/images/svg/megacategory/art__grocery.svg',
    ),
    Text('Abarrotes')
)
```

So add these two variables under your `Widget build`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 double width,height;
 width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;//This means that width== the width of the device running the app in double
 height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;//Same thing with the height
```

So now that you have the values of the device width and height you can experiment with their proportions:

```
child: Container(
 height: height*x,//for example if you want it to take place in 1/4 of the screen x=0.25
 width: width*x,//same thing here
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: ColorPallete.secondColor[50],
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
),
child: Column(
  children: [
    SvgPicture.asset(
     'assets/images/svg/megacategory/art__grocery.svg',
    ),
    Text('Abarrotes')
)
```